# Forwarding requests from Tomcat to Apache httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, httpd

Is there any way to forward requests from Tomcat to an Apache httpd server?

I know you can do it the other way around with mod_proxy_ajp, but here's what I'd like to accomplish:

We have a Java site running under Tomcat and Apache httpd is not installed. I'd like to set it up so that everything stays the same but that requests to /folder1 are forwarded to Apache and the rest of the requests stay within Tomcat.

From what I've read, the only way I could do this is change my server configuration so that Apache runs on port 80 and fowards everything to Tomcat except /folder1. But I'd like to set it up so Tomcat runs on port 80 and just sends the /folder1 requests to httpd... a lot less to change this way

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so.  I think you'd need to set up port 80 on apache and reverse proxy everything but /folder1 to tomcat.

If /folder1 is a series of static files and you are using tomcat 7, you might be able to get by aliasing /folder1 so that tomcat still serves up those files.  See the [Standard Implementation section of the Tomcat 7 Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation) for more info.